# Getting characters from the string vector

Tags: c++, string, vector, mapping

I have a string vector and trying to reach each character of each word using two loops as shown below. Is there a way not using two loops so I don't go beyond O(n) time complexity.

clarification: What I'm trying to do is converting letters to numbers as in the phone key pad then searching those numbers if they're available in the phoneNumber string.

```
  #include<bits/stdc++.h> 
  using namespace std;

  // vector<string> words={"foo","bar","car","cat","lawyer"};
  // string phoneNumber="3226773664"

  void lookup(vector<string> &words,string phoneNumber){
  string strtonumber="";
  int ascii;

  for(auto word:words ){
    strtonumber="";
    for(auto chr:word ){
      ascii=int(chr);

      if(ascii >= 97 && ascii<=99)
      strtonumber+="2";
      if(ascii >= 100 && ascii<=102)
      strtonumber+="3";
      if(ascii >= 103 && ascii<=105)
      strtonumber+="4";
      if(ascii >= 106 && ascii<=108)
      strtonumber+="5";
      if(ascii >= 109 && ascii<=111)
      strtonumber+="6";
      if(ascii >= 112 && ascii<=115)
      strtonumber+="7";
      if(ascii >= 116 && ascii<=118)
      strtonumber+="8";
      if(ascii >= 119 && ascii<=122)
      strtonumber+="9";
  
    }
    
     if (phoneNumber.find(strtonumber) != string::npos)
        cout<<"Numerical version of these words available in your Phone Number string"<<endl;
  }
```

Comment: What do you mean by _don't go beyond O(n)_? Using multiple nested loops doesn't always mean time complexity is non-linear, in your case time complexity is `O(sum of words' length)`

Comment: I agree in the worst case complexity is O(number of words x longest word in the vector). But I'm trying to get rid of nested loops as possible some how

Comment: don't fixate on big O notation. Misunderstandings based on big-O are rather common. You code has complexity `O(n)` to access `n` characters. You wont get much faster

Comment: Why? there's nothing wrong with nested loops. Of course you could use some single-responsibility approach and put the inner loop in a seperate function. But there will always be loops.

Comment: what exactly you want to do in some stuff.

Comment: to get rid of the loops you need to explain what is `// doing some stuff`. In the code you posted the loops can be removed without altering the behavior of the program

Comment: Simply, You can not optimize that.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a way not using two loops so I don't go beyond O(n) time complexity.

Nested loops are not always `O(N^2)`. Or more precisely: big-O is only meaningful when you say what `N` is. This loop is has complexity `O(N^2)`:

```
for (unsigned i=0; i < N; ++i) {
     for (unsigned j=0; j < N; ++j) {
          foo(i,j);                // <- this is called N*N times
     }
}
```

However, your loops are rather similar to

```
for (unsigned i=0; i < number_of_strings; ++i) {
     for (unsigned j=0; j < number_of_characters(i); ++j) {
          foo( words[i][j] );
     }
}
```

And `O( number_of_strings * number_of_characters )` is nothing but `O(N)` when `N` is the number of characters you want to process.

Another way to think about it is to consider what changes about complexity if you would perform the same operations on a string `"foobarcarcatlawyer"`. Nothing. If you iterate this string the number of times you convert a single character stays exactly the same.

You cannot process `N` characters in less than `O(N)`.